# Можно ли в functions.php переопределять функцию плагина wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, плагин, карусель, gallery

Всем привет. Есть сайт на wordpress и установленный плагин галереи owl-carousel в настройках которой можно изменять расположение элементов по названию и дате., но проблема в том, что сортировка по дате почему-то только в одну сторону: старшие первее, а младшие элементы добавляются в самый конец слайдера. Вот функция, отвечающая за сортировку элементов

```
 function owl_function($atts, $content = null) {
 $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'owl-carousel',
    'orderby' => get_option('owl_carousel_orderby', 'post_date'),
    'order' => 'asc',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'Carousel',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $atts['category']
        )
    ),
    'nopaging' => true
);
}
```

Можно ли в файле functions переопределить эту функцию с единственным изменением `'order' => 'asc'` на `'order' => 'desc'`, чтобы в дальнейшем можно было обновлять плагин и не заботиться, чтобы функция снова заново переопределялась?

Comment: Только если в плагине она обернута в `if (!function_exists())`

Comment: @Etki не, не обернута.. получается только ковырять плагин и больше его не обновлять?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перехватывайте action [`pre_get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts), если `$query->query_vars['post_type'] == 'owl-carousel'` - это ваш запрос, меняйте `$query->query_vars['order']` на нужный вам.

```
function owl_order_change($query) {
    if ($query->query_vars['post_type'] == 'owl-carousel') {
        $query->query_vars['order'] = 'DESC';
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'owl_order_change');
```

Comment: отлично! Спасибо, работает!